# Conditional styling with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How does one style conditionally with Styled Components?

I have a basic component that accepts a prop, but it doesn't seem to work (probably something really silly):

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Header = styled.h1`
  color: ${props => (props.name === 'john' ? 'red' : 'blue')};
`;

export default ({ name }) => <Header>Hello {name}!</Header>;
```

[image: Edit x9k1y2656q]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to pass the prop to the `Header` component:

```
export default ({ name }) => <Header name={name}>Hello {name}!</Header>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the name props to the header component, should be:

```
<Header name={name}>Hello {name}!</Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default ({ name }) => <Header>Hello {name}!</Header>;
```

In this case, `Header Component` had't any props that you defined. In `React` props is just like html attributes. But in your code, `Hello {name}` is React children, so you get the value of `props.name` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props. Last line of code need to be edited as `export default ({ name }) => <Header {...props}>Hello {name}!</Header>;`